# find xor and remainder of the given number

Tags: java, operators

Given three positive integers A, B and C. The task is to do the following operations one by one and print the results correspondingly.
Operation 1:  Print A raised to the power of B.  Let the power be P, i.e., P = POW(A, B).
Operation 2:  Print XOR of P with C.
Operation 3:  Print remainder of P when divided with C.

Hint : Storing powers of large numbers in an int may cause overflow, so make sure that you choose long for storing result.

Input:
First line contains number of testcases T. For each testcase, there will be single line containing  three positive integers A, B and C.

Output:
For each testcase, print the required answer.

User Task:
Since, this is a functional problem, you only need to complete the function operations(int a, int b, int c).

Example:
Input:
1
5 2 3

Output:
25
26
1

Explanation:
Testcase 1: 5 raised to the power 2 is 25. 25 XOR 3 is 26 and remainder when 25 is divided by 3 is 1.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. We won't just do your homework for you. We can only help you if you have specific question. As for your homework, keep in mind that you can use `Math.pow(A, B)` to raise A to the power of B and `P ^ C` to xor P and C. You can find many other math related functions here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

For power you need to use

> Math.pow(a,b)

For xor you use the ^ operator

> p ^ c

To get the remainder you need to use % mod operator

> p % c

Putting it all together:

```
  public class JavaFiddle
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      int a = 5;
      int b = 2;
      int c = 3;
      
      long p = power(a,b);
      System.out.println(p);
      
      p = xor(p, c);
      System.out.println(p);
      
      long r =  remainder(p, c);
      System.out.println(r);
      
    }
    
    public static long power(int a, int b){
        return (long) Math.pow(a,b);
    }
    
    public static long xor(long p, int c){
        return p ^ c;
    }
    
    public static long remainder(long p, int c){
        return p % c;
    }
    
  }
```

This will give the output:

> 25  26 2